# How to generate pair of 2D random points whose average distance will be some given value?

Tags: probability, geometry, statistics

Everything written below supposes 2D world.

Suppose any rectangle area. I would like to randomly generate 2 points from this area whose distance (on average) is some given value *d*.

In other words I am looking for random distribution which will generate pair of 2D points whose mean distance will be *d*.

How can I do that?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You must say something about the distribution of the single points.

Comment: @YvesDaoust they should be from normal distribution. I have updated the question.

Comment: Please be specific about these distributions. Sorry to say, but I don't think you looked seriously at your question. (In the first place, a normal distribution has unbounded extent; but there are more serious problems.)

Comment: It cannot be normal and bounded by a rectangle.

Comment: Yes that is true, sorry for that. I have updated it to uniform distribution.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand this question completely.  You want to select two points from a rectangle such that their average distance is some value $d$.  What does this have to do with selecting single points uniformly from the rectangle?  Is it supposed to be the fact that both points are uniform from the rectangle?  If that is so, they cannot also be independent, for then the average distance is fixed and cannot be modified (without changing the dimensions of the rectangle).

Comment: I agree I have not written this question properly and since I am not so good at probability/statistics I have made multiple pointless edits. My goal is to be able to generate 2 random points which will be located in given rectangle whose average distance is close or equal to some given distance d. To achieve that we need to choose proper distribution for generating random single points. I think I got what I was looking for in uniquesolution answer. My problem definition was very unclear because of my gaps in mathemathics, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I would have commented but I am not high enough so here is an answer
let $P_1$ be any random x and y coordinate, and $P_2$ will be any random angle times distance plus $P_1$
$$P_1 = \begin{Bmatrix}x & y\end{Bmatrix}$$$$P_2=\begin{Bmatrix}P_1x+\cos{\theta}\cdot d & P_1y+\sin{\theta}\cdot d\end{Bmatrix}$$

Comment: You can choose $x$ and $y$ after $\theta$ to make sure $P_2$ is inside the rectangle.  Also you might replace $d$ with a random number with mean $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the two points are independent, their difference also follows a bivariate normal distribution, and so the square of the distance follows a chi-squared distribution with parameters depending on your initial normal distribution. Some more information can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-euclidean-distance-between-two-normally-distribu).